# Get ASP.Net listbox text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listbox, each

I have used jQuery to fetch the selected values from ListBoxes to store into the database.

```
var hdn2 = "";
jQuery('select[name$=ListMyITProgramming] > option').each(function () { 
    hdn2 += jQuery(this).attr('value') + ','; 
});
alert(hdn2);
```

Can anyone help me to get selected text rather than value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `text()`:

```
var hdn2 = "";
jQuery('select[name$=ListMyITProgramming] > option').each(function () { 
    hdn2 += jQuery(this).text() + ','; 
});
alert(hdn2);
```

However you can simplify the code (and remove the trailing `,`) by using `map()`:

```
var hdn2 = jQuery('select[name$=ListMyITProgramming] > option').map(function () { 
    return this.innerHTML; // I used the native DOM property here for speed
}).get().join(',');
```